# Как работает функция sizeof?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Есть динамический массив, состоящий из записей:

```
type
  ListType = (I,R,S,C,B);
  ElementRecord = record
    case TypeList: ListType of
      I: (IntField:integer);
      R: (RealField:real);
      S: (StrField:shortstring);
      C: (CharField:char);
      B: (BoolField:boolean);
    end;
  ExtArr = Array of ElementRecord;
var
  RecList: ExtArr;
```

Дальше с ней производим такие действия (сам массив внутри класса и с ним работают методы, здесь я показываю только результат их работы, чтобы избежать лишнего кода):

```
SetLength(RecList, 1);
RecList[0].TypeList := C;
RecList[0].CharField := 'A';
Writeln(Sizeof(ExtArr), ' ', Sizeof(RecList), ' ', Sizeof(RecList[0]));
SetLength(RecList, 2);
RecList[1].TypeList := S;
RecList[1].StrField := 'test';
Writeln(Sizeof(ExtArr), ' ', Sizeof(RecList), ' ', Sizeof(RecList[1]));
```

Вывод консоли:

> 4 4 264
>   4 4 264

То есть, размер типа 4 байта, размер массива тоже 4, при этом размер записи - элемента массива - 264 байта. И всё это не зависит от содержимого элементов массива и их числа. Размер чего, всё-таки, показывает функция `sizeof` и как ей правильно пользоваться?

Comment: скорее всего второе значение, это размер адреса начала массива, а не самого массива

Comment: Первое и второе числа - размер указателя, так как динамические массивы - это ссылочные типы. Размер `ElementRecord` обусловлен самым длинным членом юниона - `shortstring`, которая может содержать 255 символов плюс сколько-то служебных байт.

Comment: Интересно, откуда берутся дополнительные 8 байт. Судя по документации http://wiki.freepascal.org/Character_and_string_types#ShortString - 255 байт на символы + 1 байт на длину (аналогично Delphi). И всё. Кодировка не включается - используется CP_ACP by default. Про выравнивание знаю :), однако куда уж ровнее 256 байт... @Risto, а не экспериментировали с {$Ax} директивой? http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/fpcdoc/prog/progsu58.html#x65-630001.1.58

Comment: Разобрался. Нулевой байт - начало вариативной части (`SizeOf(ListType) = 1`), вроде не задействуется. Сразу после него (без выравнивания) идет байт длины строки и сама строка. Итого 257 байт + выравнивание 8 байт = 264. Получается, что "лишние" байты находятся уже **после** строки. Если поставить `ListType = Word`, то строка начнется со 2 байта (смотрю дамп памяти). На общий размер это, естественно, не повлияет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое и второе числа - размер указателя, так как динамические массивы - это ссылочные типы. Размер `ElementRecord` обусловлен самым длинным членом юниона - `shortstring`, которая может содержать 255 символов плюс сколько-то служебных байтов.

Дополнение-комментарий от @kami:

Нулевой байт - начало вариативной части (SizeOf(ListType) = 1), вроде не задействуется. Сразу после него (без выравнивания) идет байт длины строки и сама строка. Итого 257 байт + выравнивание 8 байт = 264. Получается, что "лишние" байты находятся уже после строки. Если поставить ListType = Word, то строка начнется со 2 байта (смотрю дамп памяти). На общий размер это, естественно, не повлияет.